# Forcing HWADDR to correct itself in ifcfg-eth0 network script on boot CentOS 7

Tags: linux, networking, centos, virtual-machine, mac-address

**Question**:

I would like to find a way to have the HWADDR line in the ifcfg-eth0 script verify/update itself on-boot in case it changes when a clone or copy of the VM occurs. Is there a way to do so? In CentOS 6, removing the HWADDR line from the ifcfg-eth0 script made it much more dynamic, but I have yet to find a way to keep ifcfg-eth0 from changing back to ifcfg-eno1677776 without the HWADDR line in CentOS 7. Thanks in advance for the help!

---

**Background**:

I am running a CentOS 7.2.1511 virtual machine via VMware Workstation. By default CentOS 7 got rid of the **eth0** naming convention of its network scripts and is now configured to use network scripts named **ifcfg-eno1677776** or something similar. I have software that *heavily* relies on the **eth0** naming scheme. So I have re-configured my **ifcfg-eno1677776** script by:

1. Renaming `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eno1677776` to `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0`
2. Modifying **ifcfg-eth0** to be (got HWADDR from `/sys/class/net/eno1677776/address`):

   `BOOTPROTO=dhcp
   NAME=eth0
   DEVICE=eth0
   ONBOOT=yes
   NM_CONTROLLED=no
   HWADDR=00:0c:29:d6:d2:65`
3. Added **net.ifnames=0** to the end of the **GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX** line in the `/etc/sysconfig/grub` file.
4. Reboot and run ifconfig (and celebrate!):

   `eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
       inet 10.176.15.148  netmask 255.255.252.0  broadcast 10.176.15.255
       inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fed6:d265  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
       ether 00:0c:29:d6:d2:65  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
       RX packets 2141073  bytes 749959853 (715.2 MiB)
       RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
       TX packets 65237  bytes 35352127 (33.7 MiB)
       TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0`

Each time I boot, this eth0 interface remains. However, this VM is to be distributed between team members and eventually delivered to customers. This is where the problem arises. VMware is great in that you can clone a snapshot of a VM for distribution, but this changes the MAC address of the VM.

---

**EDIT:**

You must run `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` after making the change @larsks recommended below for it to work. Worked for me!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest solution is probably to disable the "predictable device naming" behavior by setting the following options on your kernel command line:

```
biosdevname=0 net.ifnames=0
```

With this in place, the first ethernet interface on your system will be named `eth0`, the second will be `eth1`, etc.  This is documented [here](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/916973).

With this in place, just remove the `HWADDR` line from your configuration file and everything should work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @larsks although this doesn't seem to work for me. Removing the HWADDR line from my eth0 network interface file brings back the "eno" named network interface when I reboot and run ifconfig regardless of the "biosdevname" change. I will continue to look at the link you sent me and see if I can get anything from there, but in the meantime, are there any other suggestions you have?

Comment: Turns out it actually worked, but only after running `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg`...I totally forgot to run this after modifying the kernel command line. Thanks again @larsks! I will make an edit in my question above to reiterate this finding as these comments are over-looked occasionally.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these kernel arguments. Was struggling a lot with HWADDR mismatch